# How I can make URL link to sheet?

Tags: api, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made sheet name list from a file and got their URL. I used hyperlink() to make these link to each sheet. Here's the code I wrote:

```
function sheetNames2() {
  var out = new Array()
  var url = "=hyperlink(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W7L9DDo_w7lNk-AE05_ghi5y8LmaAJT2EGG-yfs3gQI/edit#gid="
  var urls = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) 
    urls.push(url + sheets[i].getSheetId() + "\"\," + "\""+ sheets[i].getName()+ "\"" + ")")
  return urls   
}
```

but it doesn't work, it showed as below when I put the function I made at cell A1:

[image: example output]

Pleas tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Where's the code that actually inserts these to the sheet? We just see you returning an array in a function.

Comment: Check out this answer here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/108080